How to make a line behind dragging a curser around a website?
I'm currently working on a website with a template from cargo.
Is there any possibility to make a line behind dragging a curser over the screen?
Maybe enabling it with HTML / CSS?
I tried searching for similar things, but didn't find anything that could help me.

Are you looking to have a trailing line behind the cursor only when the cursor is being dragged across the screen?
